# How can I add an existing button/group from a ribbon tab to a new custom tab?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, vsto, add-in, ribbon

I am developing an VSTO Addin and I want to create a new tab with buttons from other tabs. I already created the new tab, but I can't succeed adding the existing buttons and groups.

Answer (score 2):

I succeeded! In the XML file, in the custom tab section, add:
for adding a group:

```
<group idMso="existing group id"></group >
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it. 
But you can't  change group (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3391b0a8-9dea-4372-b28c-ca62b9420f25/customizing-an-existing-ribbon?forum=vsto)

But you could hide and show your own override: see idea (http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win016.htm)

For ex:

```
  <!-- Set visible to false for the Clipboard group on the Home tab-->
  <tab idMso="TabHome">
    <group idMso="GroupClipboard" visible="false"/>
  </tab>


  <!-- Point to the Built-in tab to the ribbon -->
  <tab idMso="TabHome">

    <!-- Add Clipboard group -- And hear you could add your controls   >
    <group id="DupClipboard" label="Clipboard" insertBeforeMso="GroupClipboard" >
      <splitButton idMso="PasteMenu" size="large" />
      <button idMso="Cut"/>
      <button idMso="Copy"/>
      <control idMso="FormatPainter"/>

      <dialogBoxLauncher>
        <button  idMso="ShowClipboard" />
      </dialogBoxLauncher>
    </group>

  </tab>
```

Comment: The `social.msdn.microsoft.com` link in this answer is now broken, and I cannot find an archived copy of the page to link to.

Comment: The link to `rondebruin.nl` is now outdated as the relevant content has been removed from that site. Archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20160126214006/http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win016.htm - but the edit queues are full and I can't edit it into this answer right now.

Comment: I'm not sure, but https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/add-controls-to-existing-group-in-existing-ribbon/4102c843-9fb9-4352-8ae6-6debfa6e7802 might contain the same relevant information as the dead social.msdn.microsoft.com URL.